# Intersection of Adiabatic curves

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, adiabatic

Can paths of two adiabatic process intersect on a plot? This question is for both reversible and irreversible processes. There are some [answers for this question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-two-adiabatic-curves-never-cut-each-other), but they mostly address only for reversible adiabatic processes. Also, I want a physical interpretation of the processes that is, if they don't intersect then why don't and what it would be like, physically for a system.

Comment: In the previous question you speak of, it is apparent that the person who answered you understands thermodynamics much better than you. Insulting a qualified person who was trying to help you doesn’t really motivate anybody to help you again.

Comment: I am sorry for I didn't mean to insult someone. And I really respect their experience. But they said some things that were contradictory to concepts mentioned in some really credible sources. I also sent them links to these sources. Point is, these things leads discussion elsewhere & it takes far to longer to get to the answer. As you can see, we didn't get to one, in the question I mentioned.

Comment: A system undergoing an irreversible process generally aren't in thermal equilibrium (or arbitrarily close to it) and so aren't at any point on the $PV$ diagram. Different parts of the system will in general be a different pressures, so we can't talk about *the* pressure and even if it happens that the system does have a single pressure, away from equilibrium pressure and volume alone are not enough to determine the state of the system, so you cannot expect to say a great deal about what the system can and cannot do until the process is finished.

Comment: If an adiabatic reversible process and an adiabatic irreversible process start out at the same state, doesn't that automatically mean they intersect?

Comment: @BySymmetry are you suggesting that irreversible processes can't be plotted on a P-V diagram? Also doesn't on P-V diagram the intersection of curves give a point of intersection which is usually considered an equilibrium state(i.e a state after the process is finished)? Also if it is not equilibrium pressure it will be for a very short time but even so if the system has a single pressure throughout, then I think we can determine state of the system by only P&V because P-V diagrams are usually unary phase diagrams & by Gibbs phase rule they have degree of freedom equal to 2.

Comment: @ChesterMiller yes that does mean that they intersect. So, I guess if this statement is correct that two general adiabatic processes (i.e reversible or irreversible) don't intersect, then it would mean they cannot start out at same state. I would like to know if this is possible for 2 reversible adiabatics/ 2 irreversible adiabatics/1 reversible and 1 irreversible adiabatic.

Comment: Just as they can start out at the same thermodynamic equilibrium state, they can also end up in the same thermodynamic equilibrium state (but not starting from the same state).

Comment: Yes good point @ChesterMiller. Going by this approach it does appear that a reversible & an irreversible adiabatic process can intersect. But if you look at the first answer on Quora link I attached, you could prove in the same way that he did in his answer that a reversible & an irreversible adiabatic curve cannot intersect. By looking at his proof, it appears being adiabatic (either reversible or irreversible) is enough condition for 2 curves to not intersect. Conversely by your approach , things become simpler(continued in next comment).

Comment: By your approach, a reversible & an irreversible adiabatic can intersect and similarly we can also show that 2 irreversible adiabatics also can intersect(by taking 2 different types of irreversibilities for each process, say friction for one and temperature gradients(& hence heat transfer at finite temperature difference) inside system for another). But would two irreversible adiabatic processes having different types of irreversibilities but same starting equilibrium state turn out to be different? If yes then it would also be true for 2 irreversible adiabatic process that they can intersect.

Comment: Also by your approach, it appears that two reversible adiabatic processes cannot intersect because we can have two different types of irreversibilities but total reversibility is just one condition and cannot have a variant, so we cannot have two or more reversible adiabatic processes starting out at same equilibrium state or even ending at one.

Comment: I don't see how you can possibly say that, when all I need to do is cite one single example in which an adiabatic reversible process and an adiabatic irreversible process start out in the same initial state.  By the way, I don't know whether it's appropriate to ask this, but I'm going to do so anyway:  Why are you spending so much of your valuable time speculating about esoteric things like this when you could be spending it so much more productively solving actual practice problems involving adiabatic reversible and irreversible processes?

Comment: In case you didn't notice, I am agreeing with you here that It does appear with your approach that a reversible adiabatic & an irreversible one can indeed start out in the same initial state but I cannot ignore the proof mentioned on Quora link above, by which it appears being adiabatic is the only condition one needs for curves not to intersect(if you could please check it out, if you haven't already). Regarding your esoteric comment, before asking this question, I didn't know that it was esoteric, because it seemed like a basic concept. Although I must say, good advice.

Comment: The real question is whether it is possible for an adiabatic reversible process and  an adiabatic irreversible process to start and end in the same initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states.  The answer is no, because the entropy change for an adiabatic reversible process is zero, and the entropy change for an adiabatic irreversible process is greater than zero.

Comment: @ChesterMiller When you say the entropy change for an adiabatic irreversible process is greater than zero, are you referring to the total entropy change (system + surroundings) or just that of the system. I think it's the former.

Comment: Serious advice here: it is a common mistake for beginner students of thermodynamics to get caught up in definitions. There are lots of complicated new words, so you end up spending all day debating the exact meaning of "irreversible quasistatic quasiequilibrium adiabatic isochore", getting the feeling that you're uncovering some deep knowledge. The reality is, it really doesn't matter. These words were made to describe real things. If you've said all this and still don't know how a car engine works, you're wasting your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question, yes two (different) adiabatic paths can intersect in a plot.  See State A in Fig 2. However, for this to be possible, at least one of them has to be irreversible. For different ***reversible*** adiabatic processes involving the same working substance, their plots cannot intersect. See Fig 1.

Now, if you ***could*** have two reversible adiabatic processes intersect and be connected by a reversible isothermal process, there would be a violation of the second law.  In that context, the answer to the linked question where both adiabatic processes are shown as reversible, would be correct. That is because both the system and the surroundings would return to their original states with no increase in entropy.

However, since at least one adiabatic process must be irreversible, then the cycle A-B-C-A shown in Fig 2 below would not violate the Kelvin-Plank statement of the second law.  Recall the law states:

“It is impossible to construct a device which operates on a cycle and produces ***no other effect*** (my emphasis) than the production of work and the transfer of heat from a single body”.

The irreversible adiabatic process (Process A-B) in Fig 2 produces an increase in entropy. Thus cycle A-B-C-A ***does constitute some other effect*** than the production of work and transfer of heat from a single body, and therefore does not violate the Kelvin-Plank statement of the second law.

Hope this helps 
[image]

Comment: Can a reversible adiabatic and irreversible adiabatic curve intersect more than once?

Comment: No they can't intersect more than once.

Comment: Can u give a proof as to why?

Comment: Sure. For any adiabatic process there is no heat transfer between the system and the surroundings. If two adiabatic processes intersected more than once on the PV diagram you would have a cycle in which the net work done is the area enclosed by the two curves, and yet no heat is transferred to the system. This violates the first law. For any cycle $\Delta U=0$ . For adiabatic processes $Q=0$, From first law, closed system, $\Delta U=Q-W$. Therefore, $W$ must be zero. If it isn't, it violates first law. Hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful indeed!Thank you!